# In hg, how can I drop the branch name when rebasing and/or transplanting from another repo?

Tags: version-control, mercurial, branch, rebase, transplant

Basically, what I want to try is pulling hg revisions from a branch of an experimental repo into a clone of mainline.  But I want to discard the branch name so I can push directly into the server-side mainline repo.  It's probably best to give a simple example:

```
hg init hg_mainline
pushd hg_mainline 
touch foo
hg add foo
hg commit -m 'foo'
popd
hg clone hg_mainline hg_experimental
pushd hg_experimental
hg branch bar_branch
touch bar
hg add bar
hg commit -m 'bar'
popd
pushd hg_mainline
hg pull ../hg_experimental
hg log
```

As you can see, the mainline now includes a rev with "branch: bar_branch."  I don't want this revision to have a branch (i.e. it should be default).

It is okay if this requires rewriting history with [rebase](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/RebaseExtension), [transplant](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/TransplantExtension), or another tool.  I have tried both of these, but couldn't get it working.  The most recent revision hash may end up different between the two repos.

So I want the topmost revision of hg_mainline to look like:

```
changeset:   1:xxxxxxxxxxxx
tag:         tip
user:        ...
date:        ...
summary:     ...
```

with no named branch.

Again, it's okay if the hash isn't preserved from hg_experimental.

I am currently using hg 1.6.2+55-18e1e7520b67 from an Ubuntu PPA.

EDIT:

I also used 1.3.1.  I tested the below on both, and the results here are the same.

I got it working with transplant, but only with the `grep -v` kludge.

```
hg transplant -s ../hg_experimental 1 --filter "grep -v '^branch:'"
```

With:

```
hg transplant -s ../hg_experimental 1
```

hg export didn't work either, with or without an appropriate grep.

The changeset patch looks like:

```
# HG changeset patch
# User Matthew Flaschen <EMAIL>
# Date 1282942390 14400
# Branch bar_branch
# Node ID b8e36efea72642f0a0194301489d5c48f619a921
# Parent  85d9b9773d4ec09676dfcc4af89c142c46279444
bar
```

I exported from experimental with:

```
hg export 1 -o '/tmp/%b_%H_%R'
```

and tried to import to mainline with:

```
hg import /tmp/hg_experimental_b8e36efea72642f0a0194301489d5c48f619a921_1
```

It fails with:

```
abort: no diffs found
```

EDIT 2:

As noted, the export method failed only because the files were empty.  It works correctly with `--git` or with non-empty files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution is use `hg export` from the experimental repo, and `hg import` into the main repo.  By default, `hg import` won't apply any branch information in the patch.  The downside is that they'll show up as different changesets in the two repos -- `hg incoming` in the experimental repo will show the changes you just exported/imported -- so after you do this, you may be better off deleting and recreating the experimental repo if you plan on doing any more experimentation.

EDIT: From the `hg_mainline` repository:

```
hg export -r 1 -R ../hg_experimental | hg import -
```

EDIT2: From `hg help diffs`:

> Mercurial's default format for showing changes between two versions of a file
>   is compatible with the unified format of GNU diff, which can be used by GNU
>   patch and many other standard tools.
>
> While this standard format is often enough, it does not encode the following information: (snip)
>
> - creation or deletion of empty files

The test files are empty in your test script, so you need to either enter something into them, or use the `--git` option to `hg export`.

Comment: and transplant is just a wrapper around export/import with a little duplicate detection

Comment: I get "abort: no diffs found" with either hg 1.3.1 or recent hg.  I exported and imported within versions, just to be safe.

Comment: @Matthew: Sorry, was in a hurry earlier.  Updated my answer with a command that should work for you.

Comment: No, I still get the same error.  This is immediately after doing all but the last two lines of my above test script.

Comment: Thanks, both work.  I've seen plenty of traditional diffs, but that limitation hadn't occurred to me here.  I will keep it in mind in the future, though I know it doesn't apply to much real code.

Answer (score 2):

The transplant extension already scraps the branch name:

```
cd hg_mainline
hg transplant -s ../hg_experimental 1
```

should do it for you.  If you're finding that's not the case you can always use the `--filter` modify the changesets (perhaps just using `grep -v`) on the way in.

I will note that if you can come up with a work flow that avoids transplant and retains hashes you're better off.  Avoiding named branches entirely makes this easier -- anonymous branches perhaps with bookmarks work as well or better.

Comment: There is no -`r` option.  As I noted, I experimented with transplant quite a bit, but it always kept the branch (or simply failed).

Comment: Sorry, it's not -r it's just '1'.  I just did a transplant and it threw away the branch info.  Do you have git-style diffs enabled (I don't?)?  Are you using a recent version?  1.6.3 is days old and 1.0.x (or 0.9.6) and ancient.

Comment: I got transplant working with a `grep`.  I'd heard of hg bookmarks, but didn't completely grok it before.  I've started looking into them, and it seems promising.  It certainly avoids the named branch issue.

Comment: Yeah, read http://stevelosh.com/blog/2009/08/a-guide-to-branching-in-mercurial/ and see that in Mercurial 1.6 bookmarks do push/pull with the repo.  I still prefer to just use anonymous branches with temporary multiple clones if I'm having a hard time keeping track.